# operator overloading of []

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

So I tried operator overloading of [] and it just doesn't work.
I have created this class:

```
class String
{
private:
    char* str;
public:
    String(char* str) // constructor
    {
        this->str = str;
    }
    char* Val() // returns value of this.str
    {
        return this->str;
        }
char & operator [](int index) { return this->str[index]; }
};
```

and I tried to use it like so

```
String* str = new String("example");
cout << str[2] << endl;
```

the expected result was a print of the letter 'a' but it won't work..
it does work though when I create an object like so:

```
String str("example");
cout << str[2] << endl;
```

any suggestions?

Comment: `(*str)[2]` should work, so should `str->operator[](2)`

Comment: Also please note that your String class doesn't own a copy of string that you pass to it in constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String* str = new String("example");
cout << str[2] << endl;
```

here `str` is a **pointer**, so `str[2]` is not calling your operator, but accesses the third object in memory from the address `str` which doesn't exist, thus you have Undefined Behavior.

What you need is:

```
cout << (*str)[2] << endl;
```

Comment: it's working now! thanks!
I tried addressing it as *str[2] but didn't think of using brackets..

Comment: it's because of the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 1):

`str` is a pointer to a `String`, so in `str[2]` the compiler is treating `str` as an array.

You need to access the object - so deference the pointer. i.e. `(*str)[2]`

Answer (score 1):

In the first example `str` is a pointer to a `String` object.
You need to dereference it first, and then call the operator.